# What EasingFunction is using in Windows 8 charm settings?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, windows-8, easing-functions

I make an application using WPF 4.0 (C#)

I want to know EasingFunction using in Windows 8 charm settings appeared.

[image: Windows 8 Setting Charm]

I use CubicEase, QuarticEase, PowerEase, ExponentialEase.. but I can't make
an animation like Windows 8.

How can I make an animation like windows 8 with Default based EasingFunction??

Comment: This html5 video may help http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/tracks/developing-html5-apps-jump-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of built-in windows 8 ease functions is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819806.aspx#easing_functions).  It links [this page](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/Silverlight/silverlight_next/Animations/easing_functions_gallery/testpage.html) which allows you to experiment with various easing functions.  If it's a built-in easing function, then you should be able to find it there.

Answer (score 1):

They use ExponentialEase with "EaseOut" mode.

Here's the code:

```
<Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="Trans">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.7" Value="264">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction >
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="6"/>
                    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```